# Finding pdf of $X$ given joint pdf $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(y-x)e^{-y}1_{-y<x<y,0<y<\infty}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function

So I have to find the density function of $X$ for the below function with $C = \frac{1}{4}$
$$f(x,y)=C(y-x)e^{-y},\qquad-y\lt x\lt y \quad \text{and} \quad 0 < y < \infty$$

and the solution in the book is:

[image]

So based on the comment in the book it looks like you have to find the integral for $x > 0$ and $x < 0$. Why is calculating the integral using $(0, \infty)$ wrong? Or even calculating the integral of $(0, \infty)$ for $x > 0$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ for $x < 0$ wrong?

Comment: So the integration domain is $D=\lbrace{0<y,−y<x<y\rbrace}$. As $f_{X,Y}$ is a density, it should be positive. Therefore, it is positive on $x<y$ and $−x<y$ but we know that $y>0$. This condition restricts the integration domain to $x>0$ and on $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the joint density is the area above $|x|$ (red).

[image]

So the marginal distribution is given by the following integral for any $x$:

$$f_X(x)=\int_{|x|}^{\infty}\frac14 (y-x)e^{-y}\ d y=\frac14e^{-|x|}(|x|-x+1).$$